# How to create custom action for sharepoint online 2013?through visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-actions, visual-studio-2012

am trying to create a custom action for document library for sharepoint 2013 online but am unable to get it,can any one help?

Comment: i tried to create using app for that i reffered this(http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/12/11/creating-sharepoint-ribbon-custom-actions-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Comment: but that is not creating any action in my library

Comment: please share the answer if you have for the question..

Answer (score 1):

You can use Client object model csom c# to create custom action. Try below code:

```
public static void AddCustomListAction(ClientContext clientContext)
{
    string title = "Test Ribbon Action";

    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test"); 
    UserCustomActionCollection collUCA = list.UserCustomActions;
    clientContext.Load(collUCA);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    bool found = false;
    UserCustomAction newUCAToRemove = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < collUCA.Count; i++)
    {
        if (collUCA[i].Title == title)
        {
            newUCAToRemove = collUCA[i];
            found = true;
            break;
        }
     }

     if (found)
     {
         newUCAToRemove.DeleteObject();
     }

     // Always replace existing custom action
     UserCustomAction action = collUCA.Add();
     action.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView";
     action.Sequence = 1000;
     action.Title = title;
     action.CommandUIExtension = @"<CommandUIExtension><CommandUIDefinitions>"
            + "<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children\">"
            + "<Button Id=\"InvokeAction.Button\" TemplateAlias=\"o1\" Command=\"Invoke_Command\" CommandType=\"General\" LabelText=\"Publish new items\" Image32by32=\"_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png\" Image16by16=\"_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png\" />"
            + "</CommandUIDefinition>"
            + "</CommandUIDefinitions>"
            + "<CommandUIHandlers>"
            + "<CommandUIHandler Command =\"Invoke_Command\" CommandAction=\"javascript:customFunction();\" />"
            + "</CommandUIHandlers></CommandUIExtension>";

     action.Update();

     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

Here, using the above code, a custom javascript method,  `javascript:customFunction()`  ,would be called which would be defined on the page/masterpage/page layout etc.

Output would be similar to below screengrab:

[image]

Reference - [UserCustomAction class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.usercustomaction.aspx)

[UCA using powershell](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/addremove-custom-ribbon-items-on-sharepoint-list-using-csom-powershell/)

[UCA using CSOM C#](https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/add-custom-action-through-csom-with-app/)

Comment: where should i suppose to put this c# code in Apps solution?

Comment: This is a console application which uses Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll . So, you can put it anywhere you want in the solution. In my environment, i use git repository , but you can use TFS or any other code repository and use it.

Comment: @Gautham Shett I had tried the above code and it was working  fine  only for custom lists. If i replace custom list  name with Document Library, its not working.. can you help me on this please..?

Comment: `action.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView";` change this line, it will be different in case of doc lib